# check if div has class using mutation observer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mutation-observers

I have a menu inside a div, which is closed/hidden by default. it opens when I click on it, with adding the class open to it.

```
<ul class="mydropdown-menu">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

`<ul class="mydropdown-menu">` change to `<ul class="mydropdown-menu open">` when menu is visible.

since this happens dynamically, can't use usual jquery's `hasClass` to determine whether it's there.

I heard about Mutation Observer and I tried few examples found on internet, but nothing seems to work out for me.

Can someone help me to achieve this?

I just need to know everytime my menu's `ul` element opens up/adds the open class to it, using mutation observers. how can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: You can certainly do this using a MutationObserver (see the duplicate for instructions on how), but it's really a last resort. If your code controls when this menu opens you should add the functionality there. If it's a third party library, then check they don't raise any events which you can hook to instead.

Comment: it's simple bootstrap navbar. it toggles class named open to change the state. the linked question didn't help me at all actually. so any help will be appreciated

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap then the navbar uses the standard collapsible event model, eg `shown.bs.collapse`: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/fybusknv/. With regard to the duplicate, it shows a full working example of how to set up a Mutation Observer to detect a class change. I'm not sure how much more explicit it could be.